# How do I get Local Multiplayer working on Demon's Crystals?

Tags: xbox-one, demons-crystals

I am logged in, I go to Arcade, press A to join. Player 1, picture comes up. Other 3 still flashing "Press to join"...

Turn on my daughter's controller, pressed A, but nothing happens. Tried Start (Menu or whatever it's called nowadays) and then everything else. Still nothing.

Signed her in on her controller and tried again but still nothing...

Pressed A again on my controller so it now says SELECTED on my character. Tried all of the above again, still no luck...

Is this a bug or am I being a moron?

Comment: Just added the tag and edited the title for you.